# Typescript Error Expected 0 arguments, but got 2 in Ionic Framework

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

The typescript compiler gives me this error

> typescript: src/pages/login/login.ts, line: 33
>               Expected 0 arguments, but got 2.
>         L32:  this.auth.loginAPI(this.registerCredentials)
>         L33:    .subscribe(response => {

With this code (2 files):

```
// auth-provider.ts
public loginAPI(credentials: {email:string,password:string}) {
  return this.http.post(this.apiUrl,data);
}

// login.ts
this.auth.loginAPI(this.registerCredentials)
  .subscribe(response => { 
    console.log(response);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

The funny thing is that the code works (I edit any file, my ionic serve reloads and the page renders without any problem).

Any idea?

Environment
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.5
Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node  : v8.9.3
npm   : 5.5.1
OS    : macOS High Sierra
Xcode : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

Comment: For clarification, I've tried passing two separate parametrs, a Class, even only one parameter to test it, every time I get the same compiler error. Even SublimeText highlights the error: does it means that we should do it in another way?

Comment: The problem reported by the compiler is with the .subscribe, not with the credentials passed to loginAPI. I'm editing the question to clarify it better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with the loginAPI function definition.
Adding the return type to Observable<any> made the compiler happy and solved the issue.

```
// auth-provider.ts
public loginAPI(credentials: {email:string,password:string}):Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(this.apiUrl,data);
}
```

Still I don't really understand very well why, but at least now it compiles without any error.

Comment: have you find the reason why this is happening?

Comment: @davecar21 seems to me that the compiler is forcing the declaration of the return type...

Comment: Is there any other way rather than using `Observable<any>`

Comment: @davecar21 depends on the return type of your function. What are you trying to accomplish or solve?

Answer (score 1):

In order to handler this you can create a class as follows,

```
public class credentials export {
   email : string;
   password: string;
}
```

and then,

```
public loginAPI(inCredentials : credentials ) {
  return this.http.post(this.apiUrl,data);
}
```

Comment: Tried with a Class, with an array, with two separate parameters... Doesn't work, same error every time.

Comment: what do you mean by with an array ?

Comment: I'm calling array the object I pass in my first post ( {email:string,password:string} )

Comment: I know, but doesn't work either way. Even with your proposed solution I've got the same error